# How can I render a polyline element in mxGraph?

Tags: javascript, graph, polyline, mxgraph

Does mxGraph have a specific polyline object? That is, an edge that goes through a number of points. At the moment I'm faking it using multiple straight edges linked by invisible vertices, but this messes up the graph structure.

Answer (score 1):

Waypoints can be added to edges in [mxGeometry.points](https://doc.jgraph.com/docs/js-api/files/model/mxGeometry-js.html#mxGeometry.pointseometry-js.html#mxGeometry.points). To change them you need to clone any existing geometry object (in-place changes cause undo problems):

```
var geometry = model.getGeometry(edge);
geometry = geometry.clone();
geometry.points = points;
```

Assuming edge is the edge object to alter and points is an array of [mxPoint](https://doc.jgraph.com/docs/js-api/files/util/mxPoint-js.html).

The terminal points for dangling edges can be changed via [mxGeometry.setTerminalPoint(mxPoint, boolean)](https://doc.jgraph.com/docs/js-api/files/model/mxGeometry-js.html#mxGeometry.setTerminalPoint).